# np.abs() and pd.TimedeltaIndex throws error for pd.TimedeltaIndex(['0 days']) in list

Tags: python, numpy, timedelta

I have a really strange issue with the np.abs() function in combination with a pandas TimedeltaIndex:

The following code works

```
    import numpy as np
    x=[pd.TimedeltaIndex(['1 days']), pd.TimedeltaIndex(['2 days'])]
    print(np.abs(x))

    x1=pd.TimedeltaIndex(['0 days'])
    print(np.abs(x1))
```

whereas the following throws the error:
TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.timedelta object from metadata [Y] to [ns] according to the rule 'same_kind'

```
    import numpy as np
    x=[pd.TimedeltaIndex(['0 days']), pd.TimedeltaIndex(['2 days'])]
    print(np.abs(x))
```

What is the problem here? What is the rule 'same_kind'?